# Unreliable JPEG transfer over socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, jpeg, java-threads

I am currently working on a project aimed at developing a screen share program. The program involves a client that can act as either a sender or receiver and a server that facilitates the distribution of frames to all clients connected to a specific socket.

While implementing this functionality, I have encountered issues related to program stability. Specifically, there are instances where the program appears to function correctly initially. However, as the streaming duration increases, the delay between the client and receiver grows. Additionally, on some occasions, the receiver encounters this error:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 803FFFD9
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:987)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:414)
at ScreenShareBox.receiveVideo(ScreenShareBox.java:129)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

```
//This is the client-sender code:
public void sendImageToServer(BufferedImage screenshot) {
    try {
        // Convert BufferedImage to byte array
         ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(screenshot, "jpeg", byteArrayOutputStream);

        // Get byte array from the ByteArrayOutputStream
        byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        // Get the output stream from the socket
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        // Create ObjectOutputStream for sending image bytes
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

        // Write image bytes to the ObjectOutputStream and flush the stream
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(imageBytes);
        objectOutputStream.flush();

        System.out.println("Frame sent");
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//Frames are sent every 80ms and I'm using an ExecutorService `sendImageExecutor.execute(() -> sendImageToServer(screenshot));




//This is the server code (receive and broadcast to clients):
public void receiveVideo(Socket socket, int roomId) {
    try {
        // Set up input stream to receive video frames
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

        while (true) {
            // Read the image bytes from the ObjectInputStream
            byte[] imageBytes = (byte[]) objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println("Frame Received");

            // Retrieve the list of clients in the video chat room
            List<UserWithSocket> roomClients = videoChatRoomClients.get(roomId);

            // Broadcast the received video frame to all clients in the room
            for (UserWithSocket client : roomClients) {
                // Use a thread pool to concurrently broadcast video frames to clients
                videoThreadPool.execute(() -> broadcastVideo(client, imageBytes));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void broadcastVideo(UserWithSocket user, byte[] imageBytes) {
    try {
        // Get the output stream from the user's socket
        OutputStream outputStream = user.getUserSocket().getOutputStream();

        // Write the video frame bytes to the output stream and flush
        outputStream.write(imageBytes);
        outputStream.flush();

        // Print a message indicating that the frame has been successfully broadcasted
        System.out.println("Frame Broadcasted");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



//This is the client-receiver code:
private void receiveVideo() {
    try {
        while (running) {
            // Set up input stream to receive video frames
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

            // Read the byte array representing the video frame from the ObjectInputStream
            byte[] imageBytes = (byte[]) objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println("Frame Received");
            
            // Convert the byte array to a BufferedImage
            ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
            BufferedImage receivedImage = ImageIO.read(byteArrayInputStream);
            
            // Convert BufferedImage to JavaFX Image
            Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(receivedImage, null);

             // Update the JavaFX ImageView with the received frame
            imageView.setImage(fxImage);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you need to see more of my code I'll gladly share with you. I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or guidance. Thanks in advance.

I tried changing format to PNG but the delay was even worst. I added the ExecutorService to the server too but it didn't change anything. I considered using UDP (DatagramSocket) but it would require to send many fragments that need to be reassembled so I don't really know if it's worth it. Choosing a larger time interval for sending the frames seems to help but above 100ms it's just not watchable.

Comment: Use the same object streams at both ends for the life of the connection.

Comment: known issue, already seen on this site: `ObjectOuputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` have a specific communication protocol: every time an `ObjectOutputStream` is constructed, it sends a header, which is then read and verified when an `ObjectInputStream` is created. In other words, every time one is created the other must be created (usually only once for a *connection*.) Code is apparently creating one new `ObjectOutputStream`  for each screenshot being sent, but only one single `ObjectInputStream` is created for all sreenshots on the receiving side.

Comment: I'm also wondering whether you need the byte arrays, and whether having `ImageIO` write and read directly to and from the `Object` streams would work. If so it would save you a lot of memory.